# SSIS Data Flow task providing poor performance when using a Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, ssis

I am usng a data flow task in SSIS 2008. I have the source set as an sql command. This works great for my situation. However, I only need to bring back data from the source table after a certain year. As soon as I add in this filter as a where clause, performance seems to grind to a halt. I have taken to bringing everything back and then deleting what I don't need although this is not the ideal solution.

This is the where clause. I have tried different methods to optimize the query but get the same slow data transfer:

```
where table.Date > dateadd(YY,-6,getdate())
```

Can anyone shed some light on the where clause issue?

Comment: Can you show the command?

Comment: this is the where clause. I have tried different methods to optimize the query but get the same slow data transfer - where table.Date > dateadd(YY,-6,getdate())

Comment: Because you are calculating that dateadd function everytime you compare a record. Can you set that in a variable before the Select statement and use the variable instead?

Comment: You need to be sure about this statement before you make it. These two links say that `getdate()` is not executed for every row and I'm inclined to believe it.https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/conor_cunningham_msft/2010/04/23/conor-vs-runtime-constant-functions/ http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41655/is-there-a-difference-in-performance-between-date-and-getdate

Comment: Look at the query plans of both of the cases. Sounds like you have an index for `table.Date` and it would be faster to scan the whole table than use it. Are statistics up to date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue by looking at the joins again. I had a very inefficient join which caused slow performance when combined with the where clause. Thanks for all your answers and comments.

Answer (score 0):

Add an index on the date column to the source table, and see if if performance improves.

Answer (score 0):

Is your table indexed and does the index covers the Date column? If not, the WHERE clause will require 'scanning' the table and this might be the source of the issue.

Comment: The parameter date is one that I have tried, although it doesn't significantly improve the overall performance. I am unable to index the source as it is a third party application.